Black & White Movie that ends with zombie on floor starving
My husband, who is French (mentioning in case it's a European film) remembers a film that he says was a zombie movie in black and white and the ending was basically a zombie starving on the floor of a room (maybe a bedroom).  I went to the Wikipedia zombie page and read the plot of every film listed and couldn't find any that seem to fit the bill.  Does anyone know what this film was?  It's possible he is misremembering or the scene was not at the exact end of the film, but in general 1) zombie movie 2) starving on the floor 3) black and white.  I greatly appreciate any help you can provide to help me track this down!  Thank you!

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did he watch this?  Was it at a theatre or on TV?

Do you have any more details as what you have provided already is quite generic and might cover a number of films, TV shows and even video games

Hi @DavidW it was on TV.  He says the zombie dies from starvation on the floor of the room.  He thinks it was on tv in the mid-90s in France but he has the impression that it was a very old movie even then.

Hi @A.Steer thanks, unfortunately we don't have more details.  Basically all he remembers is what I said :(  He is pretty confident that it was the very end of the film, that it ended with the zombie starved to death, he says he's 95% sure that was the end of it.
